# Range Function with variables not working when group of sheets selected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use cells as reference for a range in a excel macro, that will copy a range from all of the sheets at the same time.

```
Sheets("Codes").Select
Sheets(Array("Codes", "Totals", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",     "14", "15", "NA")).Select

Dim Copyrange As String
Startrow = Range("C18").Value 'Being a value of 19 in that cell'
Lastrow = Range("D18").Value 'Being a value of 32 in that cell'
Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":AA" & Lastrow
Range(Copyrange).Select
```

But it fails in the Range(Copyrange).select part.

If I change Range(Copyrange).select to Range("B19:AA32").Select, it works, but I want to use cells as reference.

If I run the code, in a single sheet, it works, however when I group all of them is not working.

What can I change there?

Thanks in Advance.

Don't really know what to try :(

Comment: You need to specify which sheet the range is one. Try to [Avoid Select in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `Debug.Print Copyrange` to validate `Copyrange` is a valide reference string. What does `not working` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue generated from the 2 assignment of Startrow and Lastrow.
While the Select method works on more than one sheet, when you assign a value of a cell to a variable, this will be derived from the ActiveSheet. Add a qualifier to the Cells method of the sheet name where your reference is stored.

Maybe this is "Codes" sheet.

```
Sheets("Codes").Select
Sheets(Array("Codes", "Totals", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",     "14", "15", "NA")).Select

Dim Copyrange As String
Startrow = Sheets("Codes").Range("C18").Value 'Being a value of 19 in that cell'
Lastrow = Sheets("Codes").Range("D18").Value 'Being a value of 32 in that cell'
Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":AA" & Lastrow
Range(Copyrange).Select
```

Comment: In your code, reference to the cell is done by Range method, the rule for it is the same as to the Cells method. In this context Cells(18,3) is the same as Range("C18").